# How to prevent empty bars from taking up width in Chart.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm building a bar chart in Chart.js. I have multiple data series, but often, not all of them will have a value. When this happens, even though the bars aren't there, Chart.js seems to want to allocate space for them:

[image: Chart Example]

Notice how the green and blue bars above are always left aligned relative to the labels, and how the pink and yellow are always on the right. How do I make the bars appear centered relative to their labels?

Comment: Are the empty bars linked to `null` values or `0` values?

Comment: If they are `null` values, you can try to use the [`skipNull`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#general) option. Otherwise, you could replace `0` values with `null` before passing the data to Chart.js

Comment: Adding the data in your question would be a good idea by the way.

Comment: Most lazy duplicate I have seen, litterly same problem as the question posted before this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919132/completely-hide-empty-bars-in-chart-js

Comment: @Drarig29 I left it out because there's a lot of transformation, but they're null. `skipNull` seems to actually be the missing piece of the puzzle, but now the bar has an inconsistent width. I'm going to play around with it and see what I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Drarig29's answer is correct -- `null` values plus `skipNull` removes the extra bars. However, if you're using `barPercentage`, your bars will fluctuate in width (varies from being a 1/5th of the width to 100% of the width, in my case, depending on how many bars there are), so you must set a `maxBarThickness` on the dataset to prevent them from growing.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your solution as accepted. And always read your libraries' documentation.

Comment: `skipNull` isn't working for me. Can you please provide an example?
what I have:
`data: {    datasets: [ {  data: [90, null, 0], skipNull: true } ]  },`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73425637/how-to-remove-null-value-or-0-from-bar-chart  
skipNull is not worked for me ? Can you help me to solve this issue