# Remove space between bars if one category value is null or 0 in bar chartjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js, bar-chart

[image: In this picture for plan A cycle2 is missing due to its valueis null]
How to remove this space?

I tested with this jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/cqnhe2fa/
also I modified data as

```
aDatasets1 = [65,59,80,-81,56,55,40];  
aDatasets2 = [null,30,40,50,60,20,25];
aDatasets3 = [30,20,25,65,90,34,20];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent empty bars from taking up width in Chart.js bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919671/how-to-prevent-empty-bars-from-taking-up-width-in-chart-js-bar-chart)

Comment: I used SkipNull with dataset array but its not worked for  me

Comment: "skipNull" option should be the solution but it's available since CHART.JS version 3 but it seems in jsfiddle you are using 2.6.0